# How to download courses simultaneously on react-native?

Tags: android, ios, react-native, download, react-native-fs

I am building a react-native app.The app consists of various courses. These courses are available offline.Using react-native-fs,how can I download 2 or more courses simultaneously?

```
import { Platform } from "react-native";
import RNFetchBlob from 'rn-fetch-blob'
import { _unzipAll } from "@lib/unZip";
import { DocumentDirectoryPath, LibraryDirectoryPath } from "react-native-fs";
import {
    DOWNLOADED_FILE_PATH,
    DOWNLOADED_FILE_DIRECTORY
} from "@config/constants";

let parentPath =
    Platform.OS === "ios" ? LibraryDirectoryPath : DocumentDirectoryPath;

export function downloadAllFileZip(targetPath, props, id) {
    console.log("props id val",id);
    console.log("download alll lib", props.courseofflineurl);
    try {
        RNFetchBlob.config({
            path: targetPath
        })
            .fetch(
                "GET",
                props.courseofflineurl
            )
            .progress((received, total) => {
                percentage = Math.ceil((received / total) * 100);
                console.log("percentage" + percentage)
                // getDetails(percentage);
            })
            .then(res => {
                console.log("Downloadedd", res)
                _unzipAll(targetPath, parentPath + DOWNLOADED_FILE_DIRECTORY + id, props,id);
            })
            .catch(error => { });
    } catch (error) { }
}
```

Comment: can you add some code, how you are doing it for single download?

Comment: Hey there, You need to show first what you have done.